# React: How to determine if a collection of radio buttons have a selected item?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given the following unordered HTML/JSX list:

```
<ul className="settings">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="settings" id="beginner" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
    <label htmlFor="beginner">Beginner</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="settings" id="intermediate" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
    <label htmlFor="intermediate">Intermediate</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="settings" id="expert" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
    <label htmlFor="expert">Expert</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="settings" id="custom" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
    <label htmlFor="custom">Custom</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with a submit button that fires the following function:

```
const onSubmit = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
  console.log(selectedSetting.current)
}
```

I want to validate that at least one of these radio buttons have been selected. As you can see I was using a single `useRef` variable here which would cause the "custom" radio button to be logged every time. The straight forward solution, then, is to have a useRef for each radio button but is there an easier way to do this? Can I instead give the `ul` tag a `ref` and do something similar to jQuery to see if one of them has been selected?

Comment: What does `handleSettingsChange`do?

Comment: @HMR what it does is irrelevant really. All it does is set some other state variables depending on `e.currentTarget.id`. The answer provided by Matt suggests setting a `selected` state variable by using the `e.currentTarget.id` which looks like it should work.

Comment: That answer doesn't need the ref at all since it's never used. The reason I asked is because you may choose onChange and set the value in a component that's higher up (no logic in this one and managed input) but I see that ship has sailed since you fetch data in the component. You could simplify by doing: `const selected = useRef(); onclick=e=>selected.current=e.target.id.`. Also' to give a component an id is a very bad idea since the component cannot be expected to come up with an id that's unique on the whole page, I suggest using value instead.

Comment: @HMR very good point regarding the `id`! And you're also right, I didn't need the `useRef` hook and removed it. I'll change that id thing. And yeah if that's all that I needed to do, no function would be needed but there's extra code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HMR I realized why I use `id`. Its so the labels can reference the radio buttons and will set the buttons if I click on the label. Do you have another way to do that without using the `id`? I dont think there is a way to do that.

Comment: @aarona I updated my answer to show an easier way to handle this - as HMR said, you don't need `useRef` here... The new example shows how you can handle this without the need for an ID.. (even though there is an ID, it has no effect in setting the selected radio)...

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) you don't need an id: `Alternatively, you can nest the <input> directly inside the <label>, in which case the for and id attributes are not needed because the association is implicit:`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, guys. Very appreciated.

Comment: @HMR - good call. Answer has been updated. Much, much cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the `onClick` event for the radio buttons in order to set state to the currently selected radio.

Something like this:

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
    const selectedSetting = useRef();
  
    const handleSettingsChange = e => setSelected(e.target.id);
  
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      selected 
        ? alert("Selected radio: " + selected) 
        : alert("Nothing Selected!");
    }
    
    return(
      <div>
        <ul className="settings">
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="settings" id="beginner" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="beginner">Beginner</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="settings" id="intermediate" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="intermediate">Intermediate</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="settings" id="expert" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="expert">Expert</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="settings" id="custom" ref={selectedSetting} onClick={handleSettingsChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="custom">Custom</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

This would be a much cleaner, more "React" way to accomplish this...

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const MY_RADIOS = ["Beginner", "Intermediate", "Expert", "Custom"];

function App({radios}) {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  
    const handleClick = radio => event => setSelected(radio);
  
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      let msg = selected 
        ? "Selected radio: " + selected
        : "Nothing Selected!";
      alert(msg);
    }
    
    return(
      <div>
        <ul className="settings">
          {radios && radios.map(r => {
            return (
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input onClick={handleClick(r)} type="radio" name="settings" />
                  {r}
                </label>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

render(<App radios={MY_RADIOS} />, document.body);
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;  
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```